# How to display leading zeros and percentage with python .format

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, number-formatting

How do I format percentages with leading zeros?

```
print("{:+03.2%}".format(0.12345))
```

and

```
print("{:+0>3.2%}".format(0.12345))
```

Give me +12.35% instead of +012.35%

Comment: The first number there is the _total_ number of characters (as explained in [the top scoring answer of the linked thread](/a/3604609/15497888)). To get the output you're looking for use `"{:+08.2%}".format(0.12345)` since there are are 8 characters: a plus sign (1), 3 digits (3), a decimal point (1), 2 digits (2), and a percent sign (1) = 1 + 3 + 1 + 2 + 1 = 8 (See [this answer](/a/52307635/15497888) for more explanation with .format)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and linking to the duplicate question, I'll leave it up because I failed to find the duplicate, so maybe others will too.